# how to setup model from setupcontroller hook in emberjs?

Tags: ember.js, model, controller, ember-data

I have a model hook for `/licenses` route which returns `this.store.find('license')`. But template still shows old list of licenses (not the one returned from server, which contains few licenses than those there in store). I want to forcefully update model. How can I do it using setupcontroller hook? I read somewhere that we can set model from setupController hook to forcefully update model each time the template is loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set('model', this.store.find('license'));
}
```

is this what you are looking for. This sets model for the required controller

Comment: Exactly. Thanks a lot. Could you please tell me the difference between the two (setting model from controller as you have shown, and using a model-hook to return data)..?